# Hiding and showing divs on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-frontend

I want to hide and show some elements based on a button click. As far as I know, setting display property to none should do the work. But for some reason, my code is not working. Can anyone tell me what's wrong with the code?

```js
let py = true;
document.getElementsByClassName("python")

function togglePython() {
  if (py == true) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("python").style = "display: none";
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("python").style = "display: block";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Project</h1>
<button onclick="togglePython()">Toggle</button>
<div class="python">
  <h2>Python</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>C#</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>JS</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="python">
  <h2>Python</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Note if you use jquery your entire `togglePython` function can be shortened to `$('.python').toggle();` and you can get rid of the `py` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't change the flag in your click event handler. Also, you could use jQuery methods for showing/hiding elements. I would recommend trying this out below:

```js
let showPyths = true;
const pythonElements = [...document.getElementsByClassName("python")];

function togglePython(){
  showPyths = !showPyths;
  if (showPyths){
    pythonElements.forEach((el) => el.style.display = 'block');
  } else {
    pythonElements.forEach((el) => el.style.display = 'none');
  }
}

$('#jQueryTglBtn').click(function() {
  $(pythonElements).slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Project</h1>
    <button onclick="togglePython();">Toggle</button>
    <button id="jQueryTglBtn">Toggle (jQuery slideToggle)</button>
    <div class="python">
      <h2>Python</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>C#</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>JS</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="python">
      <h2>Python</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s). The way it works is by looping through all of the elements in the document, and then applying the style to each element separately.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script>
        let py=true;
    document.getElementsByClassName("python")
    function togglePython(){
    let itms= document.getElementsByClassName("python");
      for(i=0;i<itms.length;i++){
      if (py==true)      
        itms[i].style = "display: none";
       else 
        itms[i].style = "display: block";
      }
      py=!py; //so that you can toggle multiple times
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Project</h1>
    <button onclick="togglePython()">Toggle</button>
    <div class="python">
      <h2>Python</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>C#</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>JS</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="python">
      <h2>Python</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The boolean `py` is set to `true` once and never changed that's why you get the same result every time.

Also the `getElementsByClassName` is returning a collection you need to iterate over. To make it easier I changed it to a `querySelectorAll` method with a `forEach` function to iterate over the results.

```js
let py = true;

document.querySelectorAll(".python").forEach((el) => {
  el.style = "background-color: yellow";
});

function togglePython() {
  if (py == true) {
    document.querySelectorAll(".python").forEach((el) => {
      el.style.display = "none";
    });
    py = false;
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll(".python").forEach((el) => {
      el.style.display = "block";
    });
    py = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Project</h1>
<button onclick="togglePython()">Toggle</button>
<div class="python">
  <h2>Python</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>C#</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <h2>JS</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
<div class="python">
  <h2>Python</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Would `el.style = "display: block";` overwrite other style properties?

Comment: @Splitter Yes it will, you can prevent it to set the specific property of the style object. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I usually use that approach to change some style properties. See my answer too XD

Answer (score 0):

Summary of the more insightful answers:

- *"You don't change the flag in your click event handler."* (Splitter); *"The boolean `py` is set to `true` once and never changed that's why you get the same result every time."* (Mark Baijens)
- *"…the getElementsByClassName is returning a collection you need to iterate over."* (Mark Baijens); *"getElementsByClassName returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s)."* (kapil pandey)

Vanilla JS:

```js
let py = true;
function togglePython() {
  [...document.getElementsByClassName("python")].forEach(i => {
    i.style.display = py ? "none" : "block"
  })
  py = !py
}
```

If you're using jQuery, you should go jQuery all the way:

```js
let py = true;
function togglePython() {
  $(".python").css("display", py ? "none" : "block")
  py = !py
}
```

Comment: It seems that you invert the `py` meaning. When it's true you don't show those elements. And you say "you should go jQuery all the way" but you don't use jQuery toggle, slideToggle or fadeToggle methods yourself. Also it is not a nice approach to search for elements for every mouse click. Of course, it would be ok if the elements are added dynamically, but they are static in the question. Correct me if I'm wrong about all above things.

Comment: @splitter The condition's the same as the OP's and the variable is reassigned _after_ (in your example, the condition's the opposite since the variable is reassigned _before_). You're right that `.toggle()` is probably the better approach (since the boolean flag isn't required). `.css()` is also a jQuery method and the intent was to address the comments that were quoted. You're also right that caching the selector improves performance since the elements are static "in the question" (not many elements in the question so it's probably not a concern here, but definitely something to consider).